# how to get value from list based on condition in scala

Tags: scala, iterator, spray

I have a following `val headers: List[HttpHeader]`:

```
val someList = List(Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, Set-Cookie: 
JSESSIONID=879sdf97f98s7f9a87dgssa7987; Path=/userApi/; HttpOnly)
```

Now I want to get `879sdf97f98s7f9a87dgssa7987` from the above list. So I did the following:

```
someList.iterator.filter(_.name.equals("Set-Cookie")).map { x => x.value }
```

But this doesn't gives that particular value from list.

Comment: Why are you calling `iterator` ?

Comment: Provide definition of ```HttpHeader``` object/class, are you using spray-http?

Comment: To iterate each element from list and get the one which is having name equal to `Set-Cookie`

Comment: You get that for free with `.filter` and `.map` no?

Comment: @MuratMustafin- The class is in Spray without any relevance in this context. https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-http/src/main/scala/spray/http/HttpHeader.scala

Comment: `.map` is not a terminal operation. Try to end the expression with `.headOption`.

Comment: @tsearcher- It now giving `Some(JSESSIONID=879sdf97f98s7f9a87dgssa7987; Path=/userApi/; HttpOnly)`

Comment: ```someList.filter(_.name.equals("Set-Cookie")).map { x => x.value }``` you don't need iterator

Comment: @MuratMustafin- I agree but it doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: What is the type in List? The server-part is seperated by comma, like in List, but then there are Semicolons? Some Elements split with ":", some not. What is the feedback/error message? Which Library do you use? Are someList and headers the same thing? How are they related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import spray.http.HttpHeaders.`Set-Cookie`

val sessionId: Option[String] = someList.collectFirst {
  case h: `Set-Cookie` if h.cookie.name == "JSESSIONID" => h.cookie.content
}
```

Now just handle `Option[String]` appropriately.

`.collectFirst` works like a combination of `.filter`, `.map`, and `.find`.

First, it filters headers by type `Set-Cookie`.
Second, because at this point `HttpHeader` is already casted to `Set-Cookie`, we can access its `.cookie` property and use it in our search predicate.
Third, we are asking to find a cookie with name `JSESSIONID` and get its value.

Comment: Updated my answer. Try again.

Comment: Now no compile time error but the result is not as expected. This is the result now: `Some(JSESSIONID=879sdf97f98s7f9a87dgssa7987; Path=/userApi/; HttpOnly)`

Comment: Updated my answer again. Apparently, in `spray-http` you need to call `.content` instead of `.value`.

Comment: ok got it. It will give List[String] instead of Option[String].

Comment: Right. Should've been `.collectFirst` instead of `.collect`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got it working is as follows (although I don't like using split so until we find any elegant way):

```
val sessionId = someList.filter(_.name.equals("Set-Cookie")).
map { x => x.value.split(";")(0).split("=")(1)}.headOption          
println("sessionId: "+sessionId.get)
```